How to make a prepopulated ADO field(from a template) read-only?
I need to prepopulate the "Definition of Ready" field with specific text when a new work item (e.g., User Story) is created. I’ve successfully used a template for this, but I'm unsure if it's the best approach. I also want to ensure that this field remains un-editable in any state.
I attempted to use Rules with different conditions to lock the field, but applying the Rule prevents the template from displaying the default text from the template.
Could you suggest a way to achieve both pre-population and field protection?

tried and got this msg: VS1640115: The action ReadOnly cannot be used with the action Copy when applied to the same field under the same conditions.

When you create the "Definition of Ready" field, you can choose Picklist (string) type, and set only one value as the default value, so that it can  prepopulate only one value.

When you create the work item, it will have the value for the field and cannot be changed.

If you have different values for the field, and use work item rule to lock the value, it will prevent displaying the content as you have seen.

Thanks. But, in my scenario - the number of entries will be more and not just one value

If you have more entries for the value, it means the field is editable originally. It conflicted with your expectation this field remains un-editable in any state. Hence, it's not achieved. The template you are using is the only option.

Hence, it can be achieved to lock the field value in some condition, but if someone changed the state back, the field will become editable again.
